# Can I unit-test a firestore security rule using the nodejs admin sdk?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Is it possible to use the "databaseAuthVariableOverride" when you use the initializeApp() method in nodejs, to test security rules in firestore?

Or is there another recommended way to test security rules?

Comment: I wrote a TS package to wrap Firestore using the repository pattern. There's also code to test your rules on your machine or on your CI https://github.com/freshfox/firestore-storage#tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Firestore and the Admin SDK, there is currently no mechanism to force the authentication scope to a particular user. `databaseAuthVariableOverride` only works with Realtime Database at the moment.

Please feel free to [file a feature](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) request for this.

I believe there is also currently not a working client-side SDK working for node.js that you could use to log in as a user and test rules that way. :-(
Which pretty much leaves you out of normal options, unless you want to write code that remotely controls a browser that loads the Firestore client SDK.

Comment: Ok - I filed a feature request :)